# Which is easily understandable?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

[missing words here]would be utilized in the best possible way to achieve the goals of your organization, **while at the same time continuing to develop and gain experience.**

[missing words here]would be utilized in the best possible way to achieve the goals of your organization, **while further developing and gaining experience.**

Answer (score 0):

If you cut out the description of how the entity referred to with 'missing words'is used:

> "[missing words] would be utilized [...], while further developing and gaining experience",

then it is easily seen that "further developing and gaining experience" relates directly to whatever the 'missing words' entity is. (This problem affects both versions of your text.)

Presumably, this is not what you intended to say; I assume that it is the *organization* that is supposed to be increasing its experience.

Not only that, it sounds strange to speak of an organization developing and gaining experience; are you sure you don't really mean 'expertise'?

If I were you, I would go back and carefully reconsider what you actually want to say. Perhaps, for instance, you might speak of *enabling it* [i.e. your organization] *to increase its expertise*.

In the context of this brief fragment of prose, I don't think there's much to choose between the two adverbial expressions of time that start with 'while'.

Answer (score 0):

"missing words" happen to be crucial to your question. And please utilize "would be used".